# Bash Extended Globbing gives syntax error

Tags: linux, debian, bash

Can anyone explain this:

```
$ bash
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls *.(txt|doc)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ shopt extglob
extglob         on
```

This is a debian squeeze install.  I am expecting the extglob will interpret the brackets as the beginning of a group.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because extglob doesn't work that way.  You must put one of the modifier characters at the beginning of your pattern list (`(txt|doc)` in this case), as follows (from `man bash`):

```
          ?(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
          *(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
          +(pattern-list)
                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Specifically, `ls *.*(txt|doc)` produces the behaviour I am guessing you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without the extended globbing using [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):  `ls *.{txt,doc}`